# How do I redirect all of the cURL command with POST to output towards stdout

Tags: linux, docker, curl, post

Apologies if this has been asked before but I've trawled through a lot of similar questions but wasn't able to figure out so here goes:

**I have a cURL command that does a HTTP POST.
How do I make the output to be redirected to standard output.**

The command I am using inside a **docker-container** is the following:

> curl -v -X POST "http://username:pass123@data-service:8081/api" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d @postBody

This should give an output something like:

```
Note: Unnecessary use of -X or --request, POST is already inferred.
*   Trying 172.18.0.7...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to data-service (172.18.0.7) port 8081 (#0)
* Server auth using Basic with user 'username'
> POST /v1/sources HTTP/1.1
> Host: data-service:8081
> Authorization: Basic Z38JEsJ65JI9128hhtJlZW21XQ==
> User-Agent: curl/7.52.1
> Accept: */*
> Content-Type: application/json
> Content-Length: 192
> 
* upload completely sent off: 192 out of 192 bytes
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Content-Type: application/json
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Server: Jetty(8.1.8.v20121106)
< 
{
  "action" : "GO"
* Curl_http_done: called premature == 0
* Connection #0 to host data-service left intact
}
```

How do I redirect all of this to stdout **including the returned body**.

I have tried the following but it doesn't redirect everything:

curl -vs POST "http://username:pass123@data-service:8081/api" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d @postBody 2> dev/console

Any ideas?!

Thank you.

Comment: `curl` should output to stdout unless you pass `-o` parameter. So is your problem getting it out of docker? Or does `curl` not output anything? Does it work outside of docker?

Comment: @KarstenKoop - I don't get anything with using flag `-o`. Only thing helps is when i redirect them to `> dev/console` - pls help. (Outside the container, the output is as I posted above in the question.)